# tensorflow how do one get the output the same size as input tensor after segment sum

Tags: tensorflow, segment

I'm using the tf.unsorted_segment_sum method of TensorFlow and it works.
For example:

```
tf.unsorted_segment_sum(tf.constant([0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8]),
                        tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 2, 2]), 3)
```

Gives the right result:

```
array([ 0.3,  0.5 , 1.5 ], dtype=float32)
```

I want to get:

```
array([0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

```
data = tf.constant([0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8])
gr_idx = tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_count(gr_idx)
group_sum = tf.segment_sum(data, gr_idx)
group_sup = tf.gather(group_sum, idx)
```

answer:

```
array([0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5], dtype=float32)
```